# Does Flask Support Multiple Requests on the Same TCP Stream?

Tags: python, flask, tcp

Can flask handle multiple HTTP requests from the same TCP stream?
Means I send a request, get an answer and send a request to the same/another page via the same TCP steam.

Comment: Your example doesn't match the title. Flask is single threaded and can only respond to one request at a time. But after you have sent the response, you are free to receive another request.

Comment: Flask can be threaded, but my question is if flask requires a new TCP stream (syn, syn ack, ack etc.) in order to send a new page? or multiple http requests can be sent over the same tcp stream?

Comment: "Can multiple http requests can be sent over the same tcp stream?" I doubt so. Are you aware of any frameworks that do this?